# Posting to Asp.Net Core receives null object

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm making a POST request from my Angular 7 application to a AspNet Core backend server. However when receiving the model, it's null.

I'm testing using Postman, and it works when using Postman. But it's not working when sending from the client app.

Here is my controller and controller base:

```
public class BaseController : ControllerBase {
    public readonly ILogger _logger;
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ExperienceController : BaseController {
    [HttpPost, Route("Create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Experience experience){
      // code ommited
    }
}
```

Here my service.ts code

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
// some code omitted

saveExperience(experience: Experience): Observable<Experience> {
  let url = `${this.baseUrl}/Experience/Create`;
  return this.http.post<Experience>(url, experience, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((newExp: Experience) => this.log(`Created experience ${newExp}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Experience>('saveExperience'))
  );
}
```

[image: Client Request]

The object being sent from my client app is using camel-case properties, and the model for the backend is using pascal-case. In Postman this is not affecting anything, but just in case.
[image: Postman request]

I'm really confused on why when calling from Postman it's working. But every test from the client, I'm receiving a null object.

**EDIT #1**
I removed all fields from my Experience class and used only name and description and it worked, I just found that I'm getting this issue if I have a complex property.
I have added a default constructor, initializing the property but still getting the same issue. 
Please note that I'm getting this issue only when using the Angular app, if I use Postman it's working

```
public class Experience : ExperienceBase {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // this guy here is causing the issue
    public LocationDetails LocationDetails { get; set; } 

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share request data from postman and angular client.

also can you check if you have any authorization mechanism in your MVC application, if yes,are you passing the required information to it.

Comment: Can you show us what the `Experience` object is and if it's actually initialized? a common mistake is to not properly initializing the object they are passing in the method because it's strongly typed.

Comment: We have to also see the baseUrl used. Could you try to log the url to console in your saveExperience method to make sure it's valid and the one you used in postman? And what do you mean by not working? A specific error in Dev Tools?

Comment: @Sokopa By not working, he stated that his model is null inside of the controller when making the API call.

Comment: I have added the Postman request along with  a screenshot from the object before being sent using the angular app

Comment: Try fiddler to capture the request and check the difference between the request from fiddler and postman.

Comment: Did u find any solution to this problem?